# How to monitor that an application is opened?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm implementing a desktop analytics application that needs to record the names and times of programs a user opens on the PC.  It's a C# (WPF) application that starts when the user logs on and runs without a UI.  For programs such as Word or IE it would also capture what document or Url they are viewing.

Currently I have a working solution as follows:

Install a Windows Hook for Mouse Down.  When that event fires I use p-Invoke to "GetForegroundWindow" and then use the window handle to "GetWindowThreadProcessId", with the ProcessId I can get the System.Diagnostics.Process object containing the name, start time and argument start list.  I maintain a history list so I only write a tracking entry if this processId/window handle combination has not been recorded before.

This solution does work ok but requires the mouse hook which can get dropped by Windows without any notification or ability to problematically check if it is still hooked.  Not to mention this implementation seems like a hack.

If there is a better more straightforward approach please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not do away with the mouse hook and just use a timer?

Comment: seems like you are suggesting a polling approach?  That is my backup strategy, but didn't know if that would be resource intensive as I'd have to poll about every second to get reliable results.  Then I'd still need to keep track of history to ensure I only counted each process/window once.  Let me know if I misunderstood your advise.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes - I meant polling. I don't think getting the process list once a second would be particularly resource-intensive - but you could always try it and see?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`__InstanceCreationEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event and the [`Win32_Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class to monitor the created processes.

Try this sample C# application

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;


namespace GetWMI_Info
{
    public class EventWatcherAsync 
    {
        private void WmiEventHandler(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            //in this point the new events arrives
            //you can access to any property of the Win32_Process class
            Console.WriteLine("TargetInstance.Handle :    " + ((ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent.Properties["TargetInstance"].Value)["Handle"]);
            Console.WriteLine("TargetInstance.Name :      " + ((ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent.Properties["TargetInstance"].Value)["Name"]);

        }

        public EventWatcherAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                string ComputerName = "localhost";
                string WmiQuery;
                ManagementEventWatcher Watcher;
                ManagementScope Scope;                

                Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), null);
                Scope.Connect();

                WmiQuery ="Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Within 1 "+
                "Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' ";

                Watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(Scope, new EventQuery(WmiQuery));
                Watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(this.WmiEventHandler);
                Watcher.Start();
                Console.Read();
                Watcher.Stop();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception {0} Trace {1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace);
            }

        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Listening process creation, Press Enter to exit");
           EventWatcherAsync eventWatcher = new EventWatcherAsync();
           Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution, works perfect.  And if anyone wants to know how to parse that cryptic date time for the process, here is the c# snippet.               DateTime.ParseExact(wmiDateFormat.Substring(0, 21), "yyyyMMddhhmmss.ffffff", null);

Comment: How to know when the application is closed? Is there any specific query for that case?

Comment: To detect when an application is closed try the [__InstanceDeletionEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394650(v=vs.85).aspx) class

Answer (score 2):

If you want to monitor the performance of everything that is running on Windows the way to go is the [PerformanceCounter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx). Every time an application starts windows creates dozens of performance counters to keep track of the application's ProcessID, CPU usage, Memory usage, I/O operations per second and so forth.

For example, the following code would give you Chrome's Process ID:

```
PerformanceCounter perf = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "ID Process", "chrome");
int procId = (int)perf.NextValue();
```

And you can also easily enumerate categories, instances and counters using the [PerformanceCounterCategory class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecountercategory.aspx).

You can use [Windows's PerfMon tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx) to get an idea of what information you will be able to retrieve. I suggest you take a look at the **Process** Category (using PerfMon), in which you will find a list of all active processes.

Comment: similarly to the above suggestion (by Blorgbeard), this seems to indicate a polling approach.  If I were to use this strategy I'd just monitor the Process list, I don't have any use for Performance metrics.  Let me know if there was something to this suggestion that I missed.  Thanks.