# Tracking other applications running time

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows, winforms

I'm looking at building an application to record how long a Programs/Application has been running on a windows machine throughout it's uptime.

The application will start upon windows login and from there record all program usage times by collecting start and end time.

I'm looking for an alternate method preferably event driven to capture a Programs start time and end time without polling WMI as it seems really CPU intensive for the small information I need.

If anyone has any idea of what other methods I can use to capture a Process's start and end time please throw in your ideas.

Found this topic it uses WMI but seems to be fairly event driven I will give this a try and report back my finding regarding performance 
[How to monitor that an application is opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746670/how-to-monitor-that-an-application-is-opened)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Process.GetProcesses() to get all running processes, and then register to there exit event:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var p = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach (var process in p)
        {
            try
            {
                // you can add the process to your process list, chack existence and etc...
                process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                process.Exited += Program_Exited;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //any process that you don't have credantial will throw exception...
            }

        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static void Program_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var process = (Process) sender;

        var startTime = process.StartTime;
        var endTime = process.ExitTime;


    }
```

now all you have to do is manage the process list....

Comment: Thank you, The Process.Exited event is exactly what I was looking for.
Using the Process.Exited event along with the WMI event for a new process I can gather the start and end time for each Applcation.